# how to use PID controls for linear and angular velocity in object tracking

Tags: ros, pid-controller

suppose I am tracking a moving target.

I can control my robot by linear and angular velocity, i.e.

http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html

But if I use two PIDs, one for linear velocity, another for angular velocity, it is hard to tune the parameters, because both linear velocity and angular velocity impact on the "next second" position of robot.

what is the correct way to use PID controller in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is more of a low-level controls question: you've received the cmd_vel (Twist) command and you want your robot to obey it. 
In that case, you're either doing two motions separately (stopping before you turn), or simultaneously. In the first case, you can separately tune spinning vs driving, because you're tracking that state.

More likely, you have a robot that is similar enough to a diff-drive, and you're sending a signal (ex. pwm) to each side to direct it. Let's try a simple/PID-less base; to reference background kinematics I'll point to the [first section of this paper](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~allen/F17/NOTES/icckinematics.pdf). In that case, you fuse the two values into separate values for each side. Let `d_L, d_R` be the distance of each side from the center, and `d = d_L + d_R`. Let forward velocity: `vel_fwd = (vel_L + vel_R) / 2`, and `yaw_rate [rad/sec] = ω = (vel_R - vel_L) / d`, if `d_L == d_R`. Solving unknown `vel_L, vel_R` with known `vel_fwd, yaw_rate`: `vel_L = vel_fwd - d/2 * yaw_rate`, `vel_R = vel_fwd + d/2 * yaw_rate`.

Now, to apply a PID. Let `vel_L0, vel_R0` be the current measurements; therefore the state `vel_fwd0, yaw_rate0` is known. You have target state (from the message) `vel_fwd_T, yaw_rate_T`. You have error `_err` from subtracting them. At this point, if you wanted, you could do a multivariate/linearized system control; but sticking with PID, you apply a PID to each, and you get `vel_fwd_pid, yaw_rate_pid`. You can just substitue them back into your original equations for `vel_L, vel_R`.
Personally, I usually just find adding Proportional terms all over the place `vel_L = vel_fwd_T * k0 - d/2 * yaw_rate_T * k1`, `vel_R = vel_fwd_T * k2 + d/2 * yaw_rate_T * k3`, with acceleration/velocity/yaw_rate limits to be sufficient. This is because one side may not have the same curve as another, but is close-enough with an added proportional/linear boost, and the tunings on the rotation terms can be tweaked to deal with the floor/wheel/ground conditions you're expecting. Honestly, you're less likely to waste time if you try applying affine or ramp functions instead of full PID curves for driving, to get the right smoothness you need.

Comment: If you want more info, you might be better served on the https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control robotics stack exchange. If you have a more ros-y question than actual control, then the question did not seem to ask it.

Answer (score 0):

Nice and very helpful summary @JWCS

Just want to add for more clarity, calculation of vel_L and vel_R:

> vel_L = vel_fwd - (d/2 * yaw_rate)

,

> vel_R = vel_fwd + (d/2 * yaw_rate)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).